Why am I getting poorer Lighthouse Performance scores after minimising my CSS?
I'm trying to improve my site's speed. I have an isolated development version of the website hosted on a staging server and am running Lighthouse tests against it (I take the average scores of 5 consecutive test).
Whilst most changes I do (eg minimising images, lazyloading, defering JS, etc) have positive results on my score, for some reason reducing my .CSS file size does not. Compared to running the Lighthouse tests against the original, larger CSS file, my results are worse.
I'm not sure why this would be. Would anyone have any ideas? (Note neither of these files are cached.)

Are you comparing like-for-like in terms of everything else to do with css - ie same amount of files and not splitting into critical/deferred?

@RichardB yes I am. I have split out critical inline css for both cases and am testing both the original and reduced CSS file with the inline critical CSS.

Is the site faster or slower? Automated scoring systems are not always accurate when looking at systems as complex as a web page. Are you paid to make the site go faster or to get a better lighthouse score?
